# No ROLLUP and CUBE in PostgreSQL 9.4?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, rollup

I have some queries containing rollup and cube statements. When I run them on a computer with PostgreSQL 9.4 and PgAdmin III, it says that such functions don't exist. The same queries clearly have worked on another computer with PgAdmin III.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed. `ROLLUP` and `CUBE` were only introduced in PostgreSQL 9.5 - see the [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/release-9-5.html).